# Arrangement of two unequal-sized images next to each other

Tags: floats, captions

I would like to display two pictures of different sizes next to each other, the pictures should be centered in relation to each other. But I also want the captions to be at the same height. So the caption of the small picture should not slide upwards.

My current code:

```
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
        \begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image1.jpg}
            \caption{Caption 1}
            \label{fig:label1}
        \end{minipage}
            \hspace{.1\linewidth}
        \begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image2.jpg}
            \caption{Caption 2}
            \label{fig:label2}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
```

[image: output]

The picture shows the current output. As already mentioned, I would like the caption 2 to be at the same height as the caption 1 (red marking).

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You might try placing a "strut" in the minipage that holds the smaller shape.  That would be a rule of zero width, and equal height and depth that are each half the height of the larger figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to measure.

I set the two images in a three-column tabular, where the middle column is just used for adding horizontal space in between.

In your own document, remove the `height` instructions that are used here to fake different sizes (and also `showframe`). Fine tune the spacings and dimensions to your liking. And *never* use `[H]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\newcommand{\localwd}{0.4\columnwidth}% local command
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% we don't need padding

\begin{tabular}{p{\localwd} c p{\localwd}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{%
  \begin{tabular}{c}
  \includegraphics[height=6cm,width=\localwd]{example-image}
  \end{tabular}%
} &\hspace*{0.1\columnwidth}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{%
  \begin{tabular}{c}
  \includegraphics[height=3cm,width=\localwd]{example-image}
  \end{tabular}%
}
\\
\caption{First caption} && \caption{Second caption}
\end{tabular}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The trick is to use `c` for the cells containing the images and to nest them in an inner `tabular`, so they will be vertically centered with respect to the other one. For the captions, the `p` specifier is necessary and will ensure top alignment of the captions in case they occupy more than one line.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image]

- Your code fragment doesn't tell us anything about your document.t
- Please, always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a complete small document, which reproduce your problem.
- Your problem can be simple solved by inserting your images and captions in separate table rows. For example

  - by use of the `tabularx` table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\includegraphics[height=55mm, width=\linewidth, valign=m]{example-image-a}
    &   \includegraphics[height=33mm,width=\linewidth, valign=m]{example-image-b}     \\
\caption{Caption 1}
    &   \caption{Caption 2}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

- or by `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}}
\includegraphics[height=55mm, width=\linewidth, valign=m]{example-image-a}
    &   \includegraphics[height=33mm,width=\linewidth, valign=m]{example-image-b}     \\
\caption{Caption 1}
    &   \caption{Caption 2}
\end{tabular}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.

Comment: Works great, thanks for the help. I changed your `\begin{table}` with a `\begin{figure}` so the two pictures are listed as figures, not as tables.

Comment: @Simon, OK, now I corrected this.

Answer (score 0):

You can align both `minipage`s at the `[b]`ottom (which aligns the `\caption`s vertically, if they are of similar length), and then raise the smaller image into position (half the difference between the two image's heights).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\imgbox}% To store stuff

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \global\setbox\imgbox=\hbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-9x16}}% Save largest image
    \usebox\imgbox% Print image
    \caption{Caption 1}
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \raisebox{\dimexpr0.5\ht\imgbox-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-10x16}}
    \caption{Caption 2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```